# Success part of ajax function not executed sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm coding a personnal website but I have encounterd a little problem. The aim of this little part of the website is only to execute sql command.

I use ajax to call a php function from another file as shown in this part of code :

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'send.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {functionname : 'test', arguments: [rep1,rep2,rep3,rep4,rep5,rep6,rep7,rep8,rep9,rep10,rep11,rep12,rep13]},

                    success: function (obj, textstatus) {
                                  if(!('error' in obj) ) 
                                  {
                                      if(obj.result == "success")
                                      {
                                        messageErreur('Merci d\'avoir pris le temps de répondre à notre questionnaire.', '');
                                      }
                                  }
                                  else 
                                  {
                                      messageErreur(obj.error, 'Erreur');
                                  }
                            }
                    });
```

This is the script called by the ajax function :

```php
<?php 

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $aResult = array();

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "amorino";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


        if ($conn->connect_error) 
        {
            $aResult['error'] = "Erreur avec la connexion a la base de donnees.";
        }
        else
        {
            if(isset($_POST['arguments']))
            {
                $reponses = $_POST['arguments'];
                $isNotNumeric = false;
                foreach($reponses as $response)
                {
                    if(!is_numeric($response))
                    {
                        $isNotNumeric = true;
                    }
                }
                if($isNotNumeric)
                {
                    $aResult['error'] = "Impossible de traiter les réponses";
                }
                else
                {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `reponses`(`premiere_fois_chez_amorino`, `comment_connu_marque`, `quelle_tranche_age`, `vous_etes`, `vous_etes_venus`, `gamme_produit_suffisante`, `prix_et_informations_visibles`, `respectueux_environnement`, `recommandation`, `amelioration`, `experience_globale`, `qualite`, `rapport_qualite_prix`, `date_reponse`) VALUES (".$reponses[0].",".$reponses[1].",".$reponses[2].",".$reponses[3].",".$reponses[4].",".$reponses[5].",".$reponses[6].",".$reponses[7].",".$reponses[8].",".$reponses[9].",".$reponses[10].",".$reponses[11].",".$reponses[12].",\"".date("Y-m-d")."\")";

                    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
                    {
                        $aResult['result'] = "success";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $aResult['error'] = "Impossible d'envoyer votre réponse, veuillez réessayer plus tard";
                    }

                    $conn->close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $aResult['error'] = "Impossible de récupérer les arguments";
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($aResult);
?>
```

When everything works well, the sql command is well executed and the ajax function calls the function messageErreur()

But I want to try if everything works on this little script, so I tried to put a wrong database host or username. The PHP script returns properly the information:

```
{"error":"Erreur avec la connexion a la base de donnees."}
```

but the ajax function doesn't execute the success part of it and so doesn't call the function `messageErreur(obj.error, 'Erreur');`

I've tried to debug the php script and the javascript but the problem doesn't come from the php part. The only thing that I can tell you is that the php script is called but the success part of the ajax function is not called.

Need help !

Thank You !!

Comment: The `success` handler only works when the status code of the response is in the 200-302 range. Anything else is an error, and hence you need to add an `error` handler function. See the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation states

> Success: A function to be called if the request succeeds.

If the request did not succeed, then this function will not be called. In that instance,  you can use jqXHR.fail(). There is also jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.always() and jqXHR.then().

For example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'send.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            functionname: 'test',
            arguments: [rep1, rep2, rep3, rep4, rep5, rep6, rep7, rep8, rep9, rep10, rep11, rep12, rep13]
        }
    }).done(function (obj, textstatus) {
        if (!('error' in obj)) {
            if (obj.result == "success") {
                messageErreur('Merci d\'avoir pris le temps de répondre à notre questionnaire.', '');
            }
        } else {
            messageErreur(obj.error, 'Erreur');
        }
    }).fail(function (obj, textstatus, error) {
        //your error handler
    });
```

You should definitely read over the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for ajax